# Recommended place/folder to put single jar server app for deployment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-deployment, executable-jar

I have a single jar server app (simple web portal) built with Spring Boot. I run it:

`java -jar myapp.jar`

Locally, the jar file is under my Eclipse project folder. Now it's ready to be deployed on a Linux server as a service. What folder should I create on the server to put the jar file? In that folder (working directory), I will be putting the application.yaml file plus some other config files. The service will run as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directory under either `/opt` or `/usr` and have your jar run from there.

If your app creates one log file, configure it for `/var/log`. If it's going to write a few create a directory  `/var/log/<your app>`.